# jQuery - Replacing image sources dynamically for mouse events

Tags: jquery, replace, this, image, src

I've got a sample navigation list with images as buttons.  There are two additional states for the buttons for when the user hovers over the button and when the mouse is clicked.  Each button has the same naming convention, so for the back button there will be "back.jpg", "back_over.jpg", and "back_down.jpg".  Since there will be several buttons on a page, my goal is to get the path of the selected image's source, and then just modify it by appending/removing the appropriate part of the path.

I have a working example, however I feel it could be more elegant.  For example, I'm pretty sure it's possible just to store each of the 3 image paths as variables and pass them in somehow.  But when I tried that method, the img src wouldn't append or remove correctly.  I also know this is possible with CSS, which I have already done.  This is mainly to increase my understanding of jQuery.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('li > img').bind('mouseenter mousedown mouseup mouseleave click', function(event) {

            var overImgSrc = $(this).attr('src').match(/[^\.]+/) + '_over.jpg';
            var downImgSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('_over.jpg', '_down.jpg');
            var upImgSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('_down.jpg', '_over.jpg');
            var outImgSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('_over.jpg', '.jpg');

            var evtType = event.type;

            switch (evtType) {
                case 'mouseenter':
                $(this).attr('src', overImgSrc);
                break;

                case 'mousedown':
                $(this).attr('src', downImgSrc);
                break;

                case 'mouseup':
                $(this).attr('src', upImgSrc);
                break;

                case 'mouseleave':
                    if ($(this).attr('src', downImgSrc)) {
                        var downOutImgSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('_down.jpg', '.jpg');
                        $(this).attr('src', downOutImgSrc);
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).attr('src', outImgSrc);
                    }
                break;

                case 'click':
                alert("Yowza!");
                break;

                default:
                break;
            }
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
        <li><img src="images/Back.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/Next.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your if statement is setting the src `if ($(this).attr('src', downImgSrc))`

Comment: By the way, the extra bit in the mouseleave case was to prevent the iamge src from appending incorrectly if the user clicked the button then dragged the mouse out before releasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li > img').bind('mouseenter mousedown mouseup mouseleave click', function(event) {
        var images = {
            'mouseenter' : '_over.jpg',
            'mousedown'  : '_down.jpg',
            'mouseup'    : '_over.jpg',
            'mouseleave' : '.jpg',
        };

        //Store the original source without the extension.
        if (this.originalSource == undefined) {
            this.originalSource = this.src.substring(0, this.src.lastIndexOf('.'));
        }

        var evtType = event.type;

        //Append the affector.
        if (evtType in images) {
            this.src = this.originalSource + images[evtType];
        }

        //Handle your click event. (left the switch event in case you want to do something else with other events)
        switch (evtType) {
        case 'click':
            alert("Yowza!");
            break;
        default:
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I like it, and I never would have thought to try it this way.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Store the images as an array, and reference them by index.

```
var $images = ['image1.jpg','image2.jpg'];

case 'mouseenter':
    $(this).attr('src', $images[0]);
    break;
```

crude example, but you get the idea.

edit: took out the dynamic creation because the application isn't very feasible.

Comment: The src will change for the next event, so he will end up appending '_over.jpg' over and over again in this scenario.

Comment: hes doing a string replace, not an append ... if there isnt a match, itll just leave it at _over

Comment: Thanks.  Really what I'm after here is learning more about how to manipulate the img src paths.  I feel that some different perspectives will increase my understanding of jQuery.